# Access image object from resource file

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, resx

In my project, I need to retrieve a custom image file (from disk).  If the image file does not exist at the path provided, then the app will use a default image (embedded resource).  Once I have the image, I need to resize it for use futher on in my application.

If I attempt to access only the embedded resource (Code Section 1), everything works as expected.  If attempt to place a condition on the image (Code Section 2), the object comes back with all kinds of exceptions on the object, most notably for my purposes:

```
((System.Drawing.Image)(ReportLogoToUse)).Height' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' int {System.ArgumentException}
((System.Drawing.Image)(ReportLogoToUse)).Width' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'  int {System.ArgumentException}
```

Here is my code

```
// Code Section 1
using (var myImage = Resources.sie_logo_petrol_rgb){
    // resize the image to max allowed dimensions (64 x 233)
    var resizedImage = Helpers.ResizeImage(myImage, (int)maxWidth, (int)maxHeight);    // this code executes with no errors
    pictureBox1.Image = resizedImage;
}

// Code Section 2
using (var ReportLogoToUse = Helpers.ReportLogo(filePath)){
    // resize the image to max allowed dimensions (64 x 233)
    var resizedImage = Helpers.ResizeImage(ReportLogoToUse, (int)maxWidth, (int)maxHeight);  // Invalid Parameter error
    pictureBox2.Image = resizedImage;
}

public static Bitmap ReportLogo(string filePath){
    try{
        var myImage = Image.FromFile(filePath, true);
        return (Bitmap)myImage;
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        // use the embedded logo
        using (var myResourceImage = Resources.sie_logo_petrol_rgb){
            var myImage = myResourceImage;
            return (Bitmap)myImage;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the difference between the objects in Code Section 1 and Code Section 2?  Aren't they returning the same kind of object?

Comment: Maybe the program is trying to resize the image from the resources. Look if there's something like `new Bitmap(Helpers.ReportLogo(filePath))`.

Comment: @null: the problem is in the ReportLogoToUse object before it ever uses the `Helpers.ResizeImage` function

Comment: Debug here `return (Bitmap)myImage;` both on the `try`and `catch` does it work in any of the ways? Either is a problem retriving the resource, casting it. Also try removing the `using (var myResourceImage...`

Comment: it will create an object, but the errors are the same in either case.  I've tried both with and without casting to Bitmap on the return statement (perhaps it's the method declaration that's causing the issue?)

Answer (score 0):

By removing the `using...` block in the `catch...` section, and just returning the file itself, it appears to be functioning now.

```
public static Bitmap ReportLogo(string filePath){
    try{
        return (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(filePath, true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        // use the embedded logo
        return Resources.sie_logo_petrol_rgb;
    }
}
```

Any insight as to why it works now would be greatly appreciated (because I am completely baffled).